# Git - Local repository

Tags: git

how  can i convert a local git repository to remote repository ?

I need this solution in order to pull changes from local repository (after the developer commit his changes , and before the Push to master action) and test the product before the push action(that may break the remote master).

Thanks,
Liel

Comment: Dude!  This is source control, you can always roll back.  That is the point of source control.  Maybe it is better if you make a "testing" branch, but any other workflow is kinda crazy -- you have a source control system.  It lets you mark and rollback easy.

Comment: Just clone it to the remote machine and then clone it back to your local machine. Now you can push upstream. BTW try to commit only "stable" code to the master branch. Commit into branches otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The local repository of a developer is a remote repository if you are not at the developer's station.  There is nothing that needs done to allow remote access other than allowing you access to it (file access to the .git folder should be enough).  Just set up a remote for that developer's repository and use it when pulling.

However, unless the developer has identified a branch in their local repository as public, and only commit to it when they are finished with the code, pulling from it can create some pretty strange results.

There are a number of workflows that have been developed to help avoid the trouble that can result from multiple users modifying the same code base, and make sure the code that makes it into production has been fully tested.  A search for "git workflow" will give you a good deal of reading, much of it contradictory; all of it helpful in deciding what workflow works best for your environment.